# Update currency symbol on country change in checkout page without page reload

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.4

How can i update Currency Symbol on change of country without page reload in checkout page.
i'm able to update currency but currency sybmols not getting updated.

I make an ajax call and update the currency of current store as per default magento functionality but without page refresh i'm not able to get currency symbol updated.

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StxUH.png)